# best way to position divs right css

Tags: css

I need to do a website top with some navegations tools.

It is working but I'm not confortable with. I think maybe it is not the right way to do these floating divs on the right.

I need an image on the left and two itens on the right of a full width div.

So I did:

```
<div id="menu">
    <div id="logo">LOGO</div>
    <div id="item">Settings</div>
    <div id="item">Options</div>
</div>
```

and

```
#menu{
    position:fixed;
    width:100%;
    height:50px;
    background:#fff;
}

#logo{
    float:left;
    right:30px;
}

#item{
    float:right;
    right:30px;
    margin-right:10px;
}
```

Is it ok with float right and everything else or should I change something?
[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/umajo4pm)

Comment: You can't have two elements with the same `id`. Use `class` instead. Aside from that, this looks fine to me.

Comment: you can use it like that but just change the two ids to be class   if you want you can do it to with flexbox but it's already ok

Comment: oh, thank you friends!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flexbox...no need for floats or positioning at all....and the items are in the right order.

```css
#menu {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background: #fff;
  display: flex;
}
.logo {
  margin-right: auto;
}
.item {
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id=menu>
  <div class="logo">LOGO</div>
  <div class="item">Settings</div>
  <div class="item">Options</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

on #item the right:30px does nothing if you dont specify the postion. Use

```
#item{
  float:right;
  position:relative;
  right:30px;
}
```